# Redirecting to another page in html after successful login

Tags: javascript, html

I can't redirect to another page, all it does was show the password and user I entered in the url. It does work however in links such as youtube as I use window.open(); I've tried various codes I have watched on youtube but I still dont know what to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div class="login-wrapper">
    <form action="" class="form">
        <h2> Login </h2><br>
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <label for="id">User ID </label> 
        <input type="text"
         name="id"
         id="User ID"
        placeholder="User ID"
         required /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <label>Password </label> 
        <input type="password"
         name="password"
         placeholder="Password"
        id="password" required />
     </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-btn" onclick= "auth()" style="font-size:18px;" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function auth(){
        var UserID = document.getElementById("UserID").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value; 
        if(UserID== "admin" && password=="admin123"){
    
        window.location.href="teachergui.html";
        alert("Login Successfully ");
        }
        else{
        alert("Invalid User");
        return;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove space in ID ```id="User ID"``` as @donnaS answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the value with the code :

```
var UserID = document.getElementById("UserID").value;
```

But there's a space on you UserID input :

```
<input type="text"
     name="id"
     id="User ID" //from id="User ID" to id="UserID"
     placeholder="User ID"
     required />
```

Answer (score 0):

becuse you input id is User ID you can edit it UserId
[image]

[image]
When writing JavaScript code, one should be good at observing console information